# How to enable SharePoint Online form list setting radio button "Use a custom form created in InfoPath"

Tags: infopath, custom-form, list-form

SharePoint On-Prem site is migrated to SharePoint Online and people are using the InfoPath form. For testing purpose we have changed form settings to "Use the default SharePoint form" from "Use a custom form created in InfoPath".

But now "Use a custom form created in InfoPath" is disabled and unable to select is there any PowerShell or scripts to enable
[image]

Comment: Did you try using "Modify form in InfoPath" and then publishing the InfoPath form from designer? Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes. but it gives an error ==>>"The publish operations could not be completed. It can not determine the form template was successfully published. Try publishing the form template again or change the settings to use default Sharepoint form "